# Remove item from RecyclerView GridLayout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have RecyclerView GridLayout like below image
But I don't know how can remove item. I want to create new ImageView, which appear when LongClick item and if I move this element on top of ImageView, then this element removed. Please, help me, how do it?

[image]

Comment: You can follow this tutorial .
https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.fpfcua692

Comment: @ZahidulIslam yes, but this tutorial hasn't removal GridLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First download [GitHub project](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo), like said @zahidulislam.
Edit files.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerListAdapter adapter;
private ImageView trashImage;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

    trashImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trash_can);
    adapter = new RecyclerListAdapter(this);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(final View view, final int position) {
            final ImageView trashCan = (ImageView) trashImage.findViewById(R.id.trash_can);
            trashCan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int y = SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback.y;
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            if (y < -50) {
                                trashCan.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trashcan_hover));
                            } else {
                                trashCan.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trashcan));
                            }
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            if (y < -50) {
                                RecyclerListAdapter.mItems.remove(position);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                trashCan.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trashcan));
                                trashCan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return true;
                            }
                            trashCan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }));

    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(adapter);
    ItemTouchHelper mItemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    mItemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
}
```

In **SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback** add field:

```
public static int y;
```

and expression in method `public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive)`

```
y = (int) viewHolder.itemView.getY();
```

Just drop on the top (trashcan).

Comment: This however breaks the drag and drop re-positioning logic, how do you handle that?

Comment: @ishaan in no way:)

Answer (score 1):

For swipe to delete in recyclerview check [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) library.
It has very nice api for it.

Comment: Thank you, but no. I need appear ImageView. Maybe I do it through getX, getY? If coordinates item == ImageView that item remove.

Comment: This library is irrelevant to a gridlayout. I am looking for a similar solution, have you managed to find something?

Comment: @Ishaan It has helper class for gridlayout also. check sample